# What is the difference between solo and 1 man squad in PUBG?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

In Player's Unknown Battle Grounds when playing single player there is an option for solo, and then another option for 1 man squad. What is the difference in these two options?

Answer (score 12):

**Solo** is everyone playing by themselves.

In **Squad**, you get matched up with other players until you have a team of 4.

**N-man Squad** is the same as Squad, but you don't wait for other teammates.  This means your team is at a disadvantage because it has fewer than 4 players, but it also means you get into a match quicker.  So in particular, **1-man Squad** means you'll be by yourself playing against teams of four.

Comment: Some popular players who have gotten better at the game enjoy 1 man squads because it means they have more people to kill and everyone is an enemy. It's just a different but much harder way to play.